# iOS Backgrounding mode Location Updates - but also keep a socket open

Tags: ios, xcode, sockets, ios9, multitasking

I have a navigation application that works with both `CoreLocation` (Backgrounding mode **Location updates**) as well as GPS data provided over a **UDP** connection from an external sensor.

I've noticed that when I background the app the socket goes down (which likely makes sense).

What is the procedure to keep the socket open in backgorunding?

### Idea

I thought perhaps to register as a **VoIP** app - would keep the socket open but it looks like that works differently now.

The documentation suggest implementing `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:`  but this appears to be deprecated.

I'm not sure exactly how to proceed.  Any ideas?  The best I can come up with is a hack to have my location-update handler run a check on the socket so see if there is new data -  but I'm assume there is a legitimate way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When the phone goes in stand-by all the UDP socket are closed and only TCP connection can be used. Yes probably with VOIP app you can use the UDP but in that case your app will be reject because your don't use a real VOIP service. I had the same problem ... In my case, even if the phone is in background, I want to send UDP message to a domotic system but is not possible.

Comment: Previous to iOS9 I actually had something like this working i had a background thread that was the location delegate and it also was checking on UDP connections - at the time.  Seems to have changed since 9 ... alas

Comment: My app would run - then we would background it and run another app and it would keep the socket open and get data -> I was trying to rewrite the data-stack with iOS 9 and i've run into a situation where it seems to be closing everything out.  I believe because the same thread perhaps had access to the location delegate maybe that was also triggering the socket check...

Comment: But the location delegate uses the network? (sorry But I have never used location)